# SQL cannot redeclare variable within cursor with multiple batches in procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using Microsoft's Server Management Studio 2012 for this, along with their SQL Server 2008. I am attempting to take a role (CustomerRole) and get all the users in that role, put the users into a table variable (@Roles) and use the MemberName "column" to store their logins. Ultimately I will be using this information to drop the users, their logins and eventually the role completely.

```
CREATE PROC dropLogins
    AS
DECLARE @Roles AS Table(DbRole varchar(20), MemberName varchar(50), MemberSID varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Roles
EXEC sp_HelpRoleMember CustomerRole

DECLARE Member_Cursor CURSOR
DYNAMIC
FOR
SELECT DISTINCT MemberName
FROM @Roles
EXEC sp_HelpRoleMember CustomerRole
    OPEN Member_Cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM Member_Cursor
    INTO @Roles --NOT DECLARED*
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        ALTER ROLE CustomerRole DROP MEMBER MemberName
    FETCH NEXT FROM Member_Cursor
    INTO @Roles --NOT DECLARED*
CLOSE Member_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Member_Cursor
```

The problem occurs at the areas that state `--NOT DECLARED*`. I receive the "Must declare the scalar variable "@Roles"." error in those 2 regions, though I'm not sure how I can get around this error. I understand that the error is most likely caused by the code being split up into 2 and 3 batches, though I'm unsure of how to prevent this. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a table variable called @roles.

Within the cursor, you return a field, I assume is varchar().   You cannot take the output of the cursor (a varchar field) and assign it into a table variable, they are different types

You could do

```
DECLARE @theRole VARCHAR(200)

FETCH NEXT FROM Member_Cursor into @theRole
INSERT INTO @roles (dbrole) VALUES (@theRole)
```

Or something similar

Comment: Good idea, but it seems that the code is looping constantly. The error message is `Cannot drop the principal 'MemberName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.` I think I need to look at table variables a little more to understand their functionality better. Thanks for the help.